# rename columns through function (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Following is the simple way to rename columns in pandas.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'act_name':'new_name'},inplace=False)
```

I converted it to a function:

```
def rename_columns(dataframe,act_name,new_name):
    dataframe=dataframe.rename(columns={act_name:new_name},inplace=False)
```

but it doesn't work. Where is problem?

Comment: missing `return dataframe` ?

Comment: No. doesn't work with return.

Answer (score 3):

Just return instead of assigning to new variable and not returning

```
def rename_columns(dataframe,act_name,new_name):
    return dataframe.rename(columns={act_name:new_name},inplace=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def rename_columns(dataframe,act_name,new_name):
    dataframe.rename(columns={act_name:new_name},inplace=True)
```

this should work. Yay my first reply on SO!

so either rename inplace, or return an updated data frame, as others pointed out.

Comment: thanks for the suggested edit @shubham-periwal

Comment: The second one w/ inplace=True work. Thank you. But the first one with return doesn't work

Comment: So what is the rule when using inplace = False or True?

Comment: in case of inplace = False, i.e.

`def rename_columns(dataframe,act_name,new_name):
    return dataframe.rename(columns={act_name:new_name},inplace=False)`

returned object has to be assigned to an object, i.e.:

`new_df = rename_columns(old_df, old_column_name_name, new_column_name)`